# How do I create an image in Beagle that works for Angular, Android and iOS?

Tags: beagle, beagle-android, beagle-ios, beagle-web, beagle-angular

I'd like to know how do I create an image in Beagle that is compatible with all these three platforms: Angular, Android and iOS.

It's working just fine in my Angular application, but I can't get it to work in any mobile platform.

Here's my code for the backend:

```kotlin
Image(Local.justWeb('/public/logo.png'))
```

I saw there's a `Local.both`, but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image can be of two types: local or remote. Remote images only use a URL and works the same way in any platform.

This is the case of local images though. A local image resource works differently depending on the platform. For web applications you'll always need a URL. For mobile applications you'll need an identifier to locate the resource.

In the backend, you can write `Local.justWeb` if your application has only web clients, or `Local.justMobile` if your application has only mobile clients. If you need it to work for all platforms, you can use `Local.both`.

- `Local.justWeb` accepts a single parameter: the URL relative to site's root.
- `Local.justMobile` accepts a single parameter: the identifier of the resource in mobile platforms.
- `Local.both` accepts two parameters: first: the URL for the web app; second: the identifier for mobile platforms.

In Android, first you need to import the image as a resource (resource tab > import). A resource identifier can be defined in your design system class. If you don't have a design system class yet, you can create it. See the example below:

```kotlin
package com.myapp.beagle

import com.myapp.R
import br.com.zup.beagle.android.annotation.BeagleComponent
import br.com.zup.beagle.android.setup.DesignSystem

@BeagleComponent
class DesignSystem : DesignSystem() {
    override fun image(id: String): Int? {
        return when (id) {
            "informationImage" -> android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help
            "delete" -> android.R.drawable.ic_delete
            "TestImage" -> android.R.drawable.editbox_dropdown_dark_frame
            "logo" -> R.drawable.logo // <-- your identifier goes here
            else -> android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help
        }
    }
}
```

In iOS, you just need to create the resource with name equal to the mobileId you're going to use. To create a new resource, in xCode, click in the assets folder > + button > create image.